What is the relationship between Angle of Attack and Induced Flow?


 (Image Source: Principles of flight. ATPL ground training series - Author: CAE Oxford Aviation Academy (UK) Limited 2014)

I'm studying the airplane's propeller. And I found this picture in my textbook.
I just can't figure out why they wrote 'TAS of aircraft + Induced Flow' here.
I’d really appreciate it if someone could explain the relationship between AoA and Induced Flow.
As I understand it, Induced Flow is the downward flow of air that's perpendicular to the direction of motion. But how can it affect the Angle of Attack?
I’d be grateful for any responses because I'm really confused. Thanks!

From another answer about propeller thrust, this was said: As this flow passes behind the propeller, the diameter of the induced flow is contracted and the flow velocity is increased by a factor of about two. This accelerated flow is the propeller slip stream.  Consequently, the discussion appears to be in regard to flow induced into the propeller disk by the propeller, itself.  This induced flow is particularly significant at the initiation of the takeoff run when thrust from the propeller is static and at maximum.

@Denis no worries. thank you for adding the source!

Just like for a fixed wing, also behind the trailing edge of a blade a wake is released which mainly possesses a downward movement, the so-called downwash.
But unlike a fixed wing, as soon as the blade makes a complete rotation around the hub, it bumps into its own wake; and, if there are more blades on the hub, then it bumps into their wakes as well. This swirling environment that a blade encounters in its rotation is what is called "induced flow" in your picture (aka "inflow") and it has a quite complicated nature:

Wake released by the propeller of what seems to be a Leonardo AW609 (picture source)

How can [induced flow] affect the Angle of Attack?

No matter how complicated it is, its main movement is downwards and results in a general decrease of the AoA seen by the blade, as depicted in your picture.

What is the relationship between Angle of Attack and Induced Flow?

Being so complicated, it is not possible to give a simple relation for the inflow. It can anyway be demonstrated that if the inflow remains constant along the bladespan then the drag associated to it is minimised: this is different than a wing where the induced drag is minimised if the lift along the blade is elliptical. The chord and the twist along the propeller are also chosen to try to keep the inflow constant along the span.

Just as there is downwash aft of a lifting wing, there is upwash in front. This induced flow in front of a lifting wing affects local angle-of-attack (e.g., just in front of the propeller plane of rotation) but not the true AoA of the aircraft through the air mass. Flight test nosebooms mounted in front of a nose or wing with angle-of-attack vanes have to be calibrated for upwash in order to give an indication of true AoA. The figure shown must be a top or bottom view and assume zero sideslip angle. Otherwise, the red line would not appear perpendicular to the blue line. Hope this helps.
